# Ways to install python3-dev or python3-devel on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, python3

I'm trying to use [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) on neoVIm but for this I need some packages:

1. build-essential
2. cmake
3. python3-dev

as I know, build-essential comes on Arch Linux base (so check at list) I can install cmake (also check) but which way to install [python3-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python3-dev) or libraries inside this package ?

Comment: I forgot to to put on question but also I can install Python3 some I can put check in one more package of python3-dev.

Comment: There is a [PKGBUILD for youcompleteme](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/vim-youcompleteme-git/) in the [AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository). Just use this for installing.

Comment: Thanks @finswimmer I'll try this. [YouCompleteMe issue to put Arch Linux on install instructions](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/3318)

Answer (score 3):

These are the packages I installed for YouCompleteMe:

```
sudo pacman -S cmake gcc python3
```

There is no python3-dev in arch linux because python3 in arch linux already contains all the dev headers files.

Comment: This answers the question "What are the packages you installed for YouCompleteMe". It doesn't answer the question "How to install python3-dev?"

Comment: @johnywhy arch linux ships dev header files with standard python package. There is no python-dev in arch linux for that reason.